# How to change the disabled parameter of a button, depending on instance variables. Nextcord.py

Tags: python, button, discord.py

I want to disable the button when the product store reaches one of the bounds and you can no longer click on the "Next Page" or "Past Page" button. But since you can't pass instance variables to decorators, I can't compare values and pass them to @nextcord.ui.button. Can you help with this problem? Here is my code:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from SupportClasses import BuildShop as bd
from SupportClasses import Build

class ShopBuildings(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ShopBuild(self, ctx, numberPage=1):
        shopBuildings = bd.getBuildShop()

        view = ShopPages(shopBuildings, int(numberPage))

        await ctx.send(embed=createEmded('ShopBuildings', shopBuildings[int(numberPage)-1], view=view))


class ShopPages(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, shop, numberPage):
        super().__init__()
        self.__shop = shop
        self.__numberPage = numberPage-1

    @nextcord.ui.button(label='Past Page', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def BackPage(self, button: nextcord.ui.button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        self.__numberPage-=1

        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed=createEmded('ShopBuildings', self.__shop[self.__numberPage]))

    @nextcord.ui.button(label='Next Page', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def NextPage(self, button: nextcord.ui.button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        self.__numberPage+=1
        
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=createEmded('ShopBuildings', self.__shop[self.__numberPage]))
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. As far as I know, Nextcord is a dpy fork and it would be better if you ask for help in their support server.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable buttons with self.mybutton.disabled = True.
So for your code it would be something like:

```
def __init__(self, shop, numberPage):
        super().__init__()
        self.__shop = shop
        self.__numberPage = numberPage-1
        
        if __numberPage == 0:
             self.BackPage.disabled == True

        if __numberPage == __maxPage:
             self.NextPage.disabled == True
```